# Assigning different variables in a for loop using mutate in R

Tags: r

I am trying to code a for loop which assigns a new column using the mutate function to multiple different data frames.

Without the for loop I would have a simple code like this:
In this case "i" is a placeholder for the various groupnumbers.

```
UG_Groupi <- UG_Groupi %>% mutate(pass_ID = ifelse(UG_Groupi$H_ID %in% Groupi$H_ID, TRUE, FALSE))
```

For my loop I tried this and some other variations but I can't get it to work.

```
for(i in c(1,2,3,5,10,25,40,50)){
  UG_Group <- paste0("UG_Group", i)
  assign(UG_Group, mutate(UG_Group, pass_ID = ifelse(UG_Group$H_ID %in% paste0("Group",i)$H_ID, TRUE, FALSE)))
}
```

Does someone know how I could pass the "i" to the different variables in this loop respectively get this loop to work?

Thank you.

Edit:
Here is a reproducible example. In this simplified data, all rows of the "pass_ID" column (in every UG_Group) should contain the boolean TRUE.

```
UG_Group1 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(1,2,3,4))
UG_Group2 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(5,6,7,8))
UG_Group3 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(9,10,11,12))
UG_Group5 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(18,19,20,21))
UG_Group10 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(27,28,29,30))
UG_Group25 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(46,47,48,49))
UG_Group40 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(87,88,89,90))
UG_Group50 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(35,36,37,38))

Group1 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(1:100), x = c(8888:8987))
Group2 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(1:100), x = c(8888:8987))
Group3 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(1:100), x = c(8888:8987))
Group5 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(1:100), x = c(8888:8987))
Group10 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(1:100), x = c(8888:8987))
Group25 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(1:100), x = c(8888:8987))
Group40 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(1:100), x = c(8888:8987))
Group50 <- data.frame(H_ID = c(1:100), x = c(8888:8987))
```

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example and an expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your attempt it looks you have two sets of dataframes. One with `"UG_Group"` and another with `"Group"`. We can use `mget` to get this two sets of dataframes in a list and use `transform` to add a new `pass_ID` column in `"UG_Group"` dataframes.

```
ids <- c(1,2,3,5,10,25,40,50)
list_data <- Map(function(x, y) transform(x, pass_ID = H_ID %in% y$H_ID), 
                   mget(paste0("UG_Group", ids)), mget(paste0("Group",ids)))
```

Now to put the changes back to original `"UG_Group"` dataframes, we can use `list2env`

```
list2env(list_data, .GlobalEnv)
```